# How can I check whether an element is in a nested cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

How can I check whether an element is in a nested cell array?
ex:

```
A = {{4 5 6};{6 7 8}};
b = 5;
```

The function

```
ismember(b,A{1})
```

does not work.
Is there any solution better than for-loop?

Comment: Your cell structure is two deep. You need to do `ismember(b, A{1}{1})` if you're trying to get at the numeric values.

Comment: Can you give us more info on what your data structure is? Are those inner cell arrays always 3 elements long? Is the nesting depth always the same?

Comment: And will you always be comparing against one specific value, or a list of reference values? That is, will `b`, the value you're searching for, always be one long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because each element is a cell, you don't have a choice but to use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) combined with `ismember`, which is the same as using a loop in any case.  Your cells are specifically two-deep (per Andrew Janke).  Each cell element in your cell array is **another** cell array of individual elements, so there is no vectorized solution that can help you out of this.

Assuming that each cell is just a 1-D cell array of individual elements, you would thus do:

```
A = {{4 5 6};{6 7 8}};
b = 5;
out = cellfun(@(x) ismember(b, cell2mat(x)), A);
```

Which gives us:

```
out =

     1
     0
```

This checks to see if the value `b` is in each of the nested cell arrays.  If it is your intention to simply check for its existence over the entire nested cell array, use `any` on the output, and so:

```
out = any(cellfun(@(x) ismember(b, cell2mat(x)), A));
```

Because each cell element is a cell array of individual elements, I converted these to a numerical vector by [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) before invoking `ismember`.

Comment: if A = {1 {1 2 3};2 {4 5 6};3 {7}} how can the problem solved?

Comment: Ah that wasn't part of your original question. So you're saying that your cell array can be a mixture of non-cells and cells?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My original question is solved, but this is another question!!

Comment: @mona - You should perhaps make that another question.  That requires a significant amount of additional work that doesn't merit simply editing my answer.